# Add input from cf7 form to paragraph in same form

Tags: jquery, wordpress, input, contact-form-7, paragraph

With help from Howard E I was able to show the input from a dropdown field into another field as a placeholder. You can find that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65479129/use-dropdown-input-as-placeholder-in-another-field/65494490?noredirect=1#comment116255713_65494490).

Now I would like to show the input of any type of input field into a sentence in a paragraph in that same form.

I tried this code, but unfortunately that didn’t work.

```
<p>Is [recent-years] is gonna be a good year?</p>
```

`[recent-years]` is the name of the cf7 input field. In this case a dropdown field. But also would love to know for textfields and radio/select inputfields.

I guess it’s possible with jQuery, but my knowledge isn’t that great.

Hopefully there’s someone that could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this on the form

```
<p>Is <span id="recent-years"></span> is gonna be a good year?</p>
```

And for the jQuery use this:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
   $('select[name="recent-years"]').on('change', function(){
       updateParagraph(); 
   });
  updateParagraph();
  
  function updateParagraph(){
    // Assign variable $placeholder to the chosen value
       let $placeholder = $('select[name="recent-years"]').val();
       // replace 'your-field-name' with the cf7 field name
       $('input[name="your-field-name"]').attr('placeholder', $placeholder);
       //New code to also add to the form html
       $('#recent-years').html($placeholder);
  }
});
```

Tested working, see below

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tami, that's almost the solution I need, but it doesn't work properly. When I add the code it shows the value underneath the sentence, and not in it as it should. So the value shows up, but strange enough at the wrong place.

Comment: @Vasco I can fix that, already know what the issue is. will update the answer shortly.

Comment: @Vasco I'm updating the answer now with a working version. I just realized you are the same person from the years dropdown!! :)

Comment: thanks. I also saw that the first option of the dropdown don’t show up in the paragraph. I think because it’s probably the standard value. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Yeah, I can try

Comment: OK, got it, updated the answer again. You move the functionality to a function, and call the function on load and on change. Cheers!

Comment: Yes it's me! ;-) Still learning... I added this code to the form interface but it does not work at my end. :-( I only added a sentence to the `$placeholder` like `$('input[name="your-field-name"]').attr('placeholder', "my-sentence " + $placeholder);`. But that shouldn't be a problem I think.

Comment: So the last version of the code definitely works, I updated the Gif and now you can see it displays the year on load too. I also added your sentence, which shouldn't have made any problems, and it didn't. 

Could you clarify what is it that doesn't work for you exactly? If nothing works, probably the way you are inserting the jquery is the problem, can you check the console for errors?

Comment: I used the exact same code and placed it at the top of the form and it doesn't work. So I checked the console and it says `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` which is strange in my opinion, because there's no `<` in the code. When I click on the error to see the details it shows this: `jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
$('select[name="recent-years"]').on('change', function(){
updateParagraph(); 
});
updateParagraph();</p>
<p>  function updateParagraph(){` Do you see the `<p>` and `</p>`? There not in the code...

Comment: I think the issue is: placing jquery code within the form. It looks like CF7 does not support it?
You should add this jquery either through a file, of using something like `wp_add_inline_script`. Or, perhaps your theme has an option to add JS, or through one of those insert JS plugins, that I personally hate, but would solve your problem. You need to insert your jquery code in a way that the site can render it correctly.

Comment: Perhaps you are missing encapsulating the code within <script></script> tags, but I am still not sure if CF7 will support adding JS directly in their form editor @Vasco

Comment: Thanks Tami, I encapsulated the code in the `<script> </script>` tags. And it worked before based on the other question. I could try to use a JS plugin, but as you already say, I also don't prefer that.

Comment: So the theme I use supports to add additional JS. I added the script there and it works. But still not in the sentence: [screenshot] (https://imgur.com/a/ZvvAdXc)

Comment: It must be your theme/site's css, as in my clean install that issue doesn't happen, as you can see in my gif. If you can share a URL for me to check, I should be able to figure it out tomorrow when I'm back at my PC. Without seeing the issue, I'm afraid I can't help.

Comment: Hi Tami, I tried several things but that didn't worked out. I use a div class for css `<div class="vacancy_form">` and when I delete this it works. So there is something interfering between the code and css. Please see the link to the [form](https://www.europaragraph.nl/online-belastingformulier-staging/)

Comment: Hey @Vasco , there is no form on that link that I can see, it's just a full width, full height background image with a text and nothing else...

Comment: Hi @Tami, please try this [link](https://www.europaragraph.nl/online-belastingformulier). Thanks!

Comment: Can you put the step of the form where the recent-years field is? That's a lot to fill in and many steps!

Comment: Hi @Tami, I deleted the style for now and when I did, the year appears perfectly in the sentence. So there's something with the style.

Comment: Sounds like you solved it, great. Can you accept the answer when you can, please?

Comment: Thank you @Vasco