# Display conditional text in paragraph depending on chosen value dropdown cf7

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

Base on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65765016/add-input-from-cf7-form-to-paragraph-in-same-form) thread I have a dropdown menu which shows the chosen value in sentence of the next question of the form.
Now I would also like, when one of the values is chosen, another question of the form shows some other text in the sentence, like this:

Year is dropdown value and amount is the conditional text what should be shown in the question (paragraph).

2020: 30.846,-
2019: 30.360,-
2018: 30.000,-
2017: 25.000,-
2016: 24.437,-

I've learned how to managed this with the value, but not with different text depending of the chosen value.

The code I now have to get the years:

```
<p>Did you unsubscribed yourself in <span id="recent-years"></span>?</p>
[radio radio-uitgeschreven-nl class:inline-control "Yes" "No"]
```

And to get the years:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
$('select[name="recent-years"]').on('change', function(){
   updateParagraph(); 
});
updateParagraph();

function updateParagraph(){
// Assign variable $placeholder to the chosen value
   let $placeholder = $('select[name="recent-years"]').val();
   // replace 'your-field-name' with the cf7 field name
   $('input[name="ba-maanden"]').attr('placeholder', $placeholder);
   //New code to also add to the form html
   $('#recent-years').html($placeholder);
 }
});
</script>
```

The input field ba-maanden is for something else. So that's why you see this also here.

So I would like when someone selects a specific year they'll see another amount like mentioned above in this question:

```
<p>Do you have endowment insurance or savings account of more than 30.846 EUR?</p>
[radio radio-kapitaal-spaar class:inline-control "Ja" "Nee"]
```

I guess I can put the amount between something like `<span>year-amount</span>`. But how can I pull the amount depending on the chosen year?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Best regards,

Vasco

Comment: Where is your code exemple ?

Comment: I edited the original post with the code added. Thanks.

Comment: Anyone? I'm stuck... :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this ?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('select[name="recent-years"]').on('change', function(){
     changeQuestion($(this)); 
  });
  $('input[name="confirm-insurance"]').on('change', function(){
     changeQuestion($(this)); 
  });
});

function changeQuestion(object, selector){
  let currentParagraph = $(object).closest('.question');
  let currentValue = $(object).val();
  let nextParagraph = $(object).closest('.question').next('.question');
  
  $(currentParagraph).fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $(nextParagraph).show().removeClass('hide');
    $(nextParagraph).find('.lastAnswer').text(currentValue);
  });
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="question">
  Did you unsubscribed yourself in 
  <span id="recent-years">
   <select name="recent-years">
     <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Select year</option>
     <option value="30.846">2020</option>
     <option value="30.360">2019</option>
   </select>
  </span> ?
</p>

<p class="question hide">
  Do you have endowment insurance or savings account of more than <span class="lastAnswer"></span> ?<br>Yes <input type="radio" name="confirm-insurance" value="yes"> No <input type="radio" name="confirm-insurance" value="no">
</p>

<p class="question hide">
  Your answer is <span class="lastAnswer"></span>.
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I mean. Now it works like this: When someone selects an option from the dropdown menu with the id `recent-years` that option will be shown in this paragraph: `<p>Did you unsubscribed yourself in <span id="recent-years"></span>?</p>`. Based on the selected option I would like to get another value in a new question. Example: if someones selects the answer 2021, they will see `<p>Do you have endowment insurance or savings account of more than <span id="amount"></span>?</p>` where `amount` is variable depending of the chosen option of the `recent-years` dropdown

Comment: @Vasco Check plz :)

Comment: It's not working at my end :-( But am I correct this code isn't suitable for cf7? Because that't what I'm using. Thanks.

Comment: I see on the demo it's working fine! But on my website I see this, please see this [screenshot](https://imgur.com/ajSJfDs). You can see that there's an extra select input field which isn't necessary and that the amount isn't visible in the last question. On this screenshot you see that there is an year date in the first dropdown. That year is shown in the next question (not now, normally between 'in' and 'ingeschreven'. And then based on that year date value there has to be an amount visible in the last question. Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you so much for helping me out.

Comment: Because your are using editor website to make it......

Comment: That’s correct. So how can I get this to work on my website?

Comment: Add all of this in html structure and it will work